# RegisterDeviceNotification Getting WM_DEVICECHANGE

Tags: c, winapi

I want to catch message of WM_DEVICECHANGE.But, there is a problem which i can not understand.I want to see when usb or cd inserted.Maybe my notification filter is wrong.
I m using radstudio and the language of its c,also its commandline application.I think everything is obvious in code.What am i doing wrong,i created window for only getting messages.Also i did not understand how it message going to WndProc from message loop.

```
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <dbt.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (uiMsg)
{
case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
{
    MessageBox(0,"a","b",1);
}
}
}



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

BOOL bRet;
HANDLE a;
HWND lua;
HANDLE hInstance;
MSG msg;
WNDCLASSEX wndClass;
HANDLE hVolNotify;
    DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE dbh;


DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME NotificationFilter;
  lua = CreateWindow("lua", NULL, WS_MINIMIZE, CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
            NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
                         wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
ZeroMemory(&NotificationFilter, sizeof (NotificationFilter));
NotificationFilter.dbcv_size = sizeof (NotificationFilter);
NotificationFilter.dbcv_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME;
a = RegisterDeviceNotification(lua,&NotificationFilter,DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 )) != 0)
{
    MessageBox(0,"o","b",1);
    if (bRet == -1)
    {

    }
    else
    {

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am i doing wrong,i created window for only getting messages.

You are asking `CreateWindow()` to create a window of class `"lua"` but you have not actually registered the `"lua"` class via `RegisterClass/Ex()` before calling `CreateWindow()`, and you are not checking to see if `CreateWindow()` returns a `NULL` window handle on failure.

> Also i did not understand how it message going to WndProc from message loop.

That is handled by `DispatchMessage()`.  You need to assign `wndClass.lpfnWndProc` and register it with `RegisterClass()` before calling `CreateWindow()`.  Afterwards, when `DispatchMessage()` sees a message that targets the window created by `CreateWindow()`, it knows that `WndProc()` has been associated with that window and will call it directly, passing it the message.

Try this instead:

```
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <dbt.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uiMsg == WM_DEVICECHANGE)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("WM_DEVICECHANGE"), TEXT("WndProc"), MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uiMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = reinterpret_cast<HINSTANCE>(GetModuleHandle(NULL));

    WNDCLASS wndClass = {0};
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = &WndProc;
    wndClass.lpszClassName = TEXT("lua");
    wndClass.hInstance = hInstance;

    if (RegisterClass(&wndClass))
    {
        HWND lua = CreateWindow(wndClass.lpszClassName, NULL, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
        if (lua != NULL)
        {
            DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME NotificationFilter = {0};
            NotificationFilter.dbcv_size = sizeof(NotificationFilter);
            NotificationFilter.dbcv_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME;

            HDEVNOTIFY hVolNotify = RegisterDeviceNotification(lua, &NotificationFilter, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);

            if (hVolNotify != NULL)
            {
                MSG msg;
                while( GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0 )
                {
                    TranslateMessage(&msg);
                    DispatchMessage(&msg);
                }

                UnregisterDeviceNotification(hVolNotify);
            }

            DestroyWindow(lua);
        }

        UnregisterClass(wndClass.lpszClassName, hInstance);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For added measure, you can use `CreateWindowEx()` instead of `CreateWindow()` to create a message-only window instead, if desired:

```
HWND lua = CreateWindowEx(0, wndClass.lpszClassName, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem.You helped me a lot.I was having a lot missing infomation and misunderstandings.If i was not ask,it takes a long time to solve by myself.So you are great.

Comment: I fixed a compile error, but your code does not work: `GetLastError` returns 1066 after `RegisterDeviceNotification`(hVolNotify is NULL)

Comment: After changing the struct to `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE` it fixed that problem, but creating a message-only window (as you specified) prevent the messages from being delivered for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `dbcv_unitmask` field of the `DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME` structure to indicate which drive letters you're interested in. If you want to see media changes you also need to set the `DBTF_MEDIA` flag in the `dbcv_flags` field.